# How to optimize this MySQL query from Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

This query is generated by a doctrine2 QueryBuilder (the concat function takes only 2 parameters), and it takes 4 seconds.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id_4
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  1 / LOCATE( ?, CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT(w0_.firstname, ' '),
                                                CONCAT(w0_.lastname, ' ') ), w1_.fullname ) 
                          ) AS sclr_0,
                        1 / LOCATE( ?, CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT(w0_.firstname, ' '),
                                                CONCAT(w0_.lastname, ' ') ), w1_.shortname ) 
                          ) AS sclr_1,
                        1 / LOCATE( ?, CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT(w0_.nickname, ' '),
                                                CONCAT(w0_.lastname, ' ') ), w1_.fullname ) 
                          ) AS sclr_2,
                        1 / LOCATE( ?, CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT(w0_.nickname, ' '),
                                                CONCAT(w0_.lastname, ' ') ), w1_.shortname ) 
                          ) AS sclr_3,
                        w0_.id AS id_4, w0_.slug AS slug_5, w0_.firstname AS firstname_6,
                        w0_.lastname AS lastname_7, w0_.nickname AS nickname_8,
                        w0_.gender AS gender_9, w0_.email AS email_10, w0_.email_checked AS email_checked_11,
                        w0_.title_en AS title_en_12, w0_.short_title AS short_title_13,
          -- lots of stuff removed (see edit) --
                        w5_.biography_en AS biography_en_55, w5_.created AS created_56, w5_.updated AS updated_57, w6_.id AS id_58, w6_.web_text AS web_text_59, w6_.created AS created_60
                    FROM  wmn_executive w0_
                    INNER JOIN  wmn_company w1_  ON w0_.company_id = w1_.id
                    INNER JOIN  wmn_industry w7_  ON w1_.industry_id = w7_.id
                    INNER JOIN  wmn_location w2_  ON w1_.location_id = w2_.id
                    INNER JOIN  wmn_country w3_  ON w2_.country_id = w3_.id
                    INNER JOIN  wmn_city w4_  ON w2_.city_id = w4_.id
                    LEFT JOIN  wmn_executive_link w5_  ON w0_.link_id = w5_.id
                    LEFT JOIN  wmn_web_executive w6_  ON w0_.id = w6_.executive_id
                    WHERE  w0_.original_id IS NULL
                      AND  w0_.user_id IS NOT NULL
                      AND  ( w0_.firstname LIKE ?
                              OR  w0_.lastname LIKE ?
                              OR  w0_.nickname LIKE ?
                              OR  w1_.fullname LIKE ?
                              OR  w1_.shortname LIKE ?
                              OR  w0_.title_en LIKE ?
                              OR  w0_.short_title LIKE ?
                              OR  w7_.industry_name_en LIKE ?
                              OR  w7_.industry_name_fr LIKE ?
                              OR  w3_.country_name_en LIKE ?
                              OR  w3_.country_name_fr LIKE ?
                              OR  w4_.city_name LIKE ? 
                          )
                    ORDER BY  sclr_0 DESC, sclr_1 DESC, sclr_2 DESC, sclr_3 DESC ) dctrn_result 
    ) dctrn_table
```

Comment: You don't need to nest `concat`s; it can take more than two arguments; not saying it'll help performance, but it would greatly improve readability.

Comment: Have you considered [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i have to nest concat since my doctrine2 query builder's concat function takes only 2 parameters :(
I forgot to indicate that the query is generated by a QueryBuilder
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Oh, just found a **first solution** to my own problem
Since the QueryBuilder's concat takes only 2 parameters, i just have to avoid to use this function and use some DQL to generate my own CONCAT in SQL with many parameters as i want! :-)
Thank you @Uueerdo
Still waiting any other performance tips ;-)

Comment: Your question is a vote against using doctrine2 QueryBuilder for serious use.  `OR` is bad for performance, especially across tables.  `LIKE` is bad, especially if you use a leading wild card.  EAV schema design leads to inefficient queries like this.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames
Any recommendation please?

Answer (score 0):

** The `ORDER BY` provides no benefit to the end result; remove it.

**

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id_4
```

can be simplified to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_4))
```

** All the items in the SELECT clause are not use, except for id_4; get rid of them.

**** Those 3 optimization might shrink the run time from 4.0s to maybe 3.9s.

And then you will say that this is not the real query, but merely a count?

If you are going to do a messy text scan like that, you need all those strings in one table.  Better yet, all the strings concatenated together into one column in one table.  This would be just for searching, not for display.  Then make a `FULLTEXT` index on that column.  This will solve the `OR` and `LIKE '%...'` problems.  But how to get it back into doctrine2, I don't know.